# Export to MX seems to corrupt the in-memory Dataset

Tags: export, dataset

I have a function that does a large number of calculations (by calling out to other smaller functions), and then builds a large `Dataset` object.  Then I do two things with the object:

(a) I write it to disk as an MX file using `Import`;
(b) I write the rows of the MX file to a SQL Server database (by using DatabaseLink).

So, the sequence of calls is something like this:

```
mainFunction[param1_, param2_] := Module[{dbConn, result},
    result = Composition[
        innerFunctionN,
        .
        .
        .
        innerFunction2,
        innerFunction1
    ][];
    (* At this point, result is a 250 MB Dataset object *)
    (* We now write this object to disk *)
    Export["result.mx", result]; (* This step happens correctly *)
    (* Set dbConn to a valid SQLConnection object *)
    DatabaseLink`SQLExecute[
        dbConn,
        queryBuilder[result]
    ]; (* This step fails; JDBC parse error from string to float *)
];
```

But curiously, the following succeeds:

```
mainFunction[param1_, param2_] := Module[{dbConn, result, result1},
    result = Composition[
        innerFunctionN,
        .
        .
        .
        innerFunction2,
        innerFunction1
    ][];
    (* At this point, result is a 250 MB Dataset object *)
    (* We now write this object to disk *)
    Export["result.mx", result]; (* This step happens correctly *)
    (* Set dbConn to a valid SQLConnection object *)
    (* NEW STEP: NOW READ RESULT BACK FROM DISK *)
    result1 = Import["result.mx"];
    DatabaseLink`SQLExecute[
        dbConn,
        queryBuilder[result1]
    ]; (* This succeeds! *)
];
```

This has been driving me crazy.  The only conclusion I can draw is that something about the MX write is corrupting `result` in memory.

I am currently using the second method as a workaround.  But do you have a better suggestion?  Can you please help me understand the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In the second case, is `result == result1`?

Comment: And also `result === result1`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a ready answer to your questions.  The sequence of calls `innerFunction1`, `innerFunction2`, ..., take about four hours to complete.  I will have to set off the computations once again.  But is there any reason why they should not be equal?

Comment: Not that I can think of; it sounds like a strange problem indeed, but it wouldn't be the first time there was an explanation for something I thought was surely a bug.  If a smaller working example is not possible I think you should contact Wolfram support about this.

Comment: I have no solution, but I have seen similar behavior when I was writing (relatively) large Datasets in an earlier version 10 (I think it was 10.0.1). I have never investigated what it was and just reloaded as you do in the second example (which was almost immediate in my case). I just checked and found it does not happen for my case with 10.0.2 on Windows anymore. Which version are you using?

Comment: @AlbertRetey I'm using version 10.1, the latest one.  (And my operating system is Windows 8.1 64-bit.)  Yes, I wish I understood the reason for the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't check with 10.1 at the moment, don't have it installed on my computer at this time. I think you should report this as a bug. Unfortunately I also don't know of a workaround other than reloading...